# UWP on suspended DelegateCommand serialization failed

Tags: c#, uwp, prism

I have a view and view model, the codes are

```
<prism:SessionStateAwarePage
    x:Class="MyApp.Views.SettingPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:prism="using:Prism.Windows.Mvvm"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <TextBox x:Name="Box1" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" Text="{Binding Path=Text1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="Box2" RelativePanel.Below="Box1" Text="{Binding Path=Text2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        <Button RelativePanel.Below="Box2" Command="{Binding Path=ButtonClickedCommand}">Click me</Button>
    </RelativePanel>
</prism:SessionStateAwarePage>
```

And view model

```
public class SettingPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly ISessionStateService sessionService;
    private string text1;
    private string text2;

    public SettingPageViewModel(ISessionStateService sessionService)
    {
        this.ButtonClickedCommand = new DelegateCommand<ItemClickEventArgs>(this.OnButtonClicked, this.CanButtonClick);
        this.sessionService = sessionService;
    }

    [RestorableState]
    public string Text1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.text1;
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetProperty(ref this.text1, value);
        }
    }

    [RestorableState]
    public string Text2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.text2;
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetProperty(ref this.text2, value);
        }
    }

    public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand { get; private set; }

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs e, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e, viewModelState);
    }

    private void OnButtonClicked(ItemClickEventArgs argument)
    {
        this.Text1 = "The value is set by button click";
    }

    private bool CanButtonClick(ItemClickEventArgs argument)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I launch it in VS2017 and select lifecycle event -> suspend I have exception

> {System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type
>   'Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand`1[Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemClickEventArgs]'
>   cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the
>   DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you
>   want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively,
>   you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless
>   constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized,
>   and no attributes will be required.    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String
>   message, Type type)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle
>   typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle
>   typeHandle, Type type)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type
>   objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle
>   declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType,
>   Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    at
>   WriteKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)    at
>   WriteArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean
>   verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type
>   declaredType)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type
>   objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle
>   declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType,
>   Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    at
>   WriteKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)    at
>   WriteArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean
>   verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type
>   declaredType)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type
>   objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle
>   declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType,
>   Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    at
>   WriteKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)    at
>   WriteArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer, Object graph)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(Stream
>   stream, Object graph)    at
>   Prism.Windows.AppModel.SessionStateService.d__5.MoveNext()}

But I have not event marked my command as `[RestorableState]` yet. What is wrong?

Comment: I donno why the command argument is serialized. But you don't actually use the argument (you don't use CommandParameter in the XAML binding), so to get rid of this error, could simply use a parameterless 'DelegateCommand' instead of 'DelegateCommand<T>'.

Comment: @kennyzx this is command itself, not the command argument.

Comment: I used your code and followed your steps to test, but I have not met this issue. It worked well on my side. I used the `Prism.Windows 6.3.0` and visual studio 2017 version 15.2(26430.15). My project's target platform is 15063.